Componente angular compartilhando variável entre componentes
Acredito que o problema seja simples mas nao encontro a soluçao.
O que ocorre é que tenho um array String com nome filters que é recebido dentro do componente
a cada Filho este filter recebe mais um dado, porem o que esta ocorrendo que é ao colocar isto em um NG for, é como se o próprio componente estivesse recebendo este dado preenchido
     @Input() filters!: string[];



  addFilter (name) : string[]{
   
    var arrayFilter = null
    arrayFilter = this.filters

    if(name !== undefined){
      arrayFilter.push(name)
    }


    return arrayFilter
  }


<div *ngFor="let item of itens">
  <div class="mt-2" *ngIf="item.expand && item.expand.length > 0">
    <mat-accordion displayMode="default" [multi]="true" [hideToggle]="false">
      <mat-expansion-panel class="mt-4" [hideToggle]="false">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          {{ item.Name }} - {{ item.Description }} -- {{filters}}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <app-expansive-panel-acordeon
          [itens]="item.expand" [filters]="addFilter(item.Name)"
        ></app-expansive-panel-acordeon>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </div>
</div>

Vou deixar aqui um print de um exemplo de como o filter esta carregando, o valor após o -- é referente a isto


No fim a solução foi simples
Aparentemente o componente desta forma utiliza uma referencia do Filtrer para gerenciar os dados passados o que gera este acumulo de informaçoes
a solução foi manter o código usando apenas o operador spread (...) para que ele gere um referencia única
  addFilter (name) : string[]{
   
    var arrayFilter = null
    arrayFilter = this.filters

    if(name !== undefined){
      arrayFilter.push(name)
    }


    return arrayFilter
  }

para
  addFilter (name) : string[]{
   
    var arrayFilter = [...this.filters]
  

    if(name !== undefined){
      arrayFilter.push(name)
    }


    return arrayFilter
  }

